# How to configure a "point-to-point" connection with RedHat 6.5?

Tags: networking, rhel, network-interface

My servers are hosted at Hetzner and I need to create a point-to-point connection to my gateway. The server can only reach its gateway (and its locally configured) IP addresses directly. All other packets need to be routed via the default gateway. Consequently, a /32 network needs to be set up (for reasons of network security).

Hetzner's wiki-article: http://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Netzkonfiguration_CentOS/en#Configuring_a_point-to-point_connection

Hereunder my file /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

```
DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=00:1E:45:ZZ:34:F9
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.1.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
```

Hereunder my /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0 file

```
ADDRESS0=0.0.0.0
NETMASK0=0.0.0.0
GATEWAY0=192.168.1.254
```

I restart the network: service network restart

An error appears: "RTNETLINK answers: No such Process".

The output of command "route":

```
link-local * 255.255.0.0 U 1002 0 0 eth0
```

After some search, I edit the file /etc/sysconfig/network as below:

```
NETWORKING=YES
HOSTNAME=server.domain.lan
GATEWAYDEV=eth0
```

An error appears: "RTNETLINK answers: File exists".

The output of command "route":

```
link-local * 255.255.0.0 U 1002 0 0 eth0
default    * 0.0.0.0     U 0    0 0 eth0
```

Ping to the default gateway was OK. Ping to the outside was NOK !

The only way to succeed was to manually add a "second" default route:

route add default gw 192.168.1.254 eth0

The output of command "route":

```
link-local *               255.255.0.0 U  1002 0 0 eth0
default    *               0.0.0.0     U  0    0 0 eth0
default    static.254.1.16 0.0.0.0     UG 0    0 0 eth0
```

In fact, the file route-eth0 is not needed. If I delete it, no more error during the restart.

How could you explain that ?

Is there another way to succeed ? Is this method correct ?

The problem is that when I'm disconnecting/reconnecting the network interface, the route is not automatically added...

Thanks,